# Dynamically displaying polygon symbology by number of intersecting points as point layer updates using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, intersection, spatial-join, query

I have a set of polygons (municipal boundaries) and a point layer. I'd like to (eventually) create a WebApp to show the number of points inside each municipality, but that point layer is going to be constantly updated (most likely each week).

I know a one time fix is a spatial join with number of intersection points as an attribute, but I was wondering if there was any method to query this sort of function to change as the point layer changes.

I want the symbology to update even if I add filters to the map. I could Python script it but that would only be for each write, where I want it to be truly dynamic.

Processes are planned to be done in ArcGIS Pro, but final product will be in ArcGIS Online

Comment: You tag this question as ArcPro then ask how to do something in a WebApp, suggest you edit your title/tag.  You could look into Arcade and and using the [intersects](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#intersects) to drive labelling of your data?

Comment: If you are looking to do a dynamic spatial join within ArcGIS Pro, you could script your spatial join process and schedule the geoprocessing task to run at a time that works for you. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/schedule-geoprocessing-tools.htm

Comment: @Hornbydd Sorry, I'm still flexible on doing the query entirely within ArcPro then just sharing the map itself, or doing the Querying online within AGOL. So although I did contradict myself, either of them would work.  

I think looking a bit more into Arcade might be a solution. The other answer seems to suggest something similar, so I'll take a look there. Thanks!

Comment: @Tigerwoulds This might be the solution. As I'll be running timed scripts to import and generate the point data weekly, I could also do that for the spatial join process as well. 

I doubt it, but if the spatial join could be run due to a sort of trigger (like a filter being applied) that would be ideal, but probably not possible. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualising the point count in a Polygon dynamically in ArcGIS Online is not possible. According to the ArcGIS Arcade: Visualisation page, the Arcade expressions only allow access to the `$feature` and `$view.scale` attributes - in other words you cannot access the " Geometry Intersection" between the polygon and points using this methodology.

[ArcGIS Arcade Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/profiles/#visualization)

That being said, you can use Arcade to access this interaction using a custom pop-up using this Arcade Expression:

```
var points = FeatureSetByName($map, 'Point_layer')
var countp = Count(Intersects(points,$feature))
return countp
```

So you will most likely need to pre-process this intersection in the publising of the polygon layer. Are you responsible / the owner of the polygon layer?
You could set up a script using arcpy to run a "Summarise" or **Intersect and Spatial Join** before the layer is published. Then re-publish / update the feature layer when you need it updated.

Comment: I think this is the direction I need to head. I'm the owner of all the data, which makes it easy. I already have a script to gather the point data weekly, so as another user mentioned, I could script the spatial join process to happen along with that. I appreciate that Arcade code snippet, I'll see what I can do with that, thanks for the help!